# Changing value of an attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a file input field:

```
<input class="uploadReptCtrl" id="lang_file_1" name="photo[[1,312,3]]" type="file">
```

I am trying to change the third element of the array in the `name` attribute so that it becomes:

```
<input class="uploadReptCtrl" id="lang_file_1" name="photo[[1,312,4]]" type="file">
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#lang_file_1').attr('name','photo[[1,312,4]]')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzzL1d2r/

you can store the value in a variable and set it as

```
var a = 4;
$('#lang_file_1').attr('name','photo[[1,312,'+a+']]')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzzL1d2r/1/

As you want to get the 3rd number increment it and assign it again you can do following

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
var string = $('#lang_file_1').attr('name');
var a = string.match( numberPattern );

$('#lang_file_1').attr('name','photo[[1,312,'+(++a[2])+']]');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzzL1d2r/3/

Comment: Is it possible to extract the third element from the array, so that I can increment it?

Comment: yes using regex you can get the value, convert it into integer and increment it.

Comment: @rahulv check the edited answer, if this is what you want.

Comment: I have handled this in server side. Anyway thanks @Newinjava